# How to integrate external library into KiCad

Tags: pcb-design, kicad, footprint, library

I am using KiCad (5.1.5). I got this self-made library from my lab mate he told me to make some changes to his schematic. Inside the folder that he gave consists the following folders and files:

- footprints.pretty (folder) - A ton of .kicad_mod files
- adafruit.dcm and adafruit.lib
- xxlib.dcm and xxlib.bak and xxlib.bck

I am a noob to KiCad and have no idea what these files mean and how I should even integrate them into the software. Can anyone please help me by explaining the different file-types mentioned and how to integrate or upload.

Comment: Have you even tried to read [KiCad help](https://kicad-pcb.org/help/file-formats/)?

Comment: Nope, but now that I've read it, how do I use the files together in KiCad or open them up in KiCad?

Comment: Can't you apply a little effort, really? Everything you need is there, [import libraries](https://docs.kicad-pcb.org/5.1.5/en/getting_started_in_kicad/getting_started_in_kicad.html#export-import-and-modify-library-components), [library management](https://forum.kicad.info/t/library-management-in-kicad-version-5/14636) and tons of other info

Comment: Do I just put my folder in the systems KiCad folder and expect everything to work, hmm, but it ain't working form me. Looked at importing libs which worked but what about bck, bak, dcm? I've tried whatever I can, and am requesting your help which I hope you bestow on thy pitiful self.

Comment: The very first statement in the link I provided specifically says _"KiCad does not automatically detect libraries! ... Every library ... must be added to so called library tables which are managed with library managers."_ The statement a bit below says _"Most kicad internal dialogs will only show the .lib file. KiCad knows that there also is a .dcm file with the same file name."_ Finally .bak and .bck file formats are described as _backups_, which means you do not need them unless you damage the originals. I've given you all the help you needed, you just refusing to use it.

Comment: only took me seconds with google to figure out how to do this myself, the time it took you to type the question you could have been done.

Comment: lol, I know. I've just got into this horrible slog suddenly. Like, i've been fine until now with my scheduled days but I just feel soo lazy today and want everything spoonfed. Thanks for the help @Maple

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the forum FAQ https://forum.kicad.info/t/start-here-frequently-asked-questions/8890/ in particular:

- https://forum.kicad.info/t/what-is-the-difference-between-footprints-and-symbols/8900
- https://forum.kicad.info/t/how-to-get-a-downloaded-symbol-footprint-or-full-library-into-kicad-version-5/19485
- https://forum.kicad.info/t/library-management-in-kicad-version-5/14636